# NetCDF to Raster in ArcMap 10.3 - selecting Band Dimension stalls out

Tags: arcgis-10.3, netcdf, multi-band

I am using the "Make NetCDF Raster layer" tool in ArcMap 10.3 and have had great success with relatively large files.  I usually select the Band Dimension (time) using the tool or sometimes after the raster is created under the layer properties NetCDF tab.  Either way it's been pretty fast and easy.

I'm now working with a much larger NetCDF file (2.3 GB; dimensions are 290 x 500 (x-y) and 1944 bands (time in hours)).  The NetCDF to Raster tool starts executing, and even says it's succeeded in the Results, taking about 22 minutes.  However, the output raster layer is empty, and the hourglass icon doesn't change (indicating completed).  It's now been > 6 hours and still nothing.

Is this file just too big for ArcMap to handle?  I was hoping to use the NetCDF_time_slice_export script tool to split my NetCDF up after getting it in as a raster, but I'm not sure that is possible.

Any suggestions are welcome.